# ReCaptcha в Selenium WebDriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, recaptcha

Пытаюсь авторизоваться на сайте, но при решении ReCaptcha руками(ставиться пауза в скрипте), выводится ошибка "Повторите попытку."

```
options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Саша\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Profiles");
        options.AddArgument("--profile-directory=Profile 3");
        options.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
        Browser = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver(options);
        Browser.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        Browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://discordapp.com/register");

        IWebElement email = Browser.FindElement(By.Name("email"));
        IWebElement username = Browser.FindElement(By.Name("username"));
        IWebElement password = Browser.FindElement(By.Name("password"));

        string send_email = gmail.getLine();
        string send_username = nickname.getLine();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        email.SendKeys(send_email);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        username.SendKeys(send_username);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        password.SendKeys("password");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        password.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Return);

        resumeButton.Enabled = true;
        levelAuthorize = 1;
```

Есть способ сделать возможным решение рекапчи в Selenium WebDriver

Comment: Рекапча для того и есть, чтобы фильтровать роботов.

Comment: Добавил свойство options.AddExcludedArguments(new List<string>() { "enable-automation" });, заработало

Comment: добавь как ответ к вопросу, а не как коментарий